# Compress all the files inside a folder with 7zip

Tags: 7zip

As the title, suppose I have a set of files in a folder. Is it possible to compress every of them in separate files? Something like

```
7z *
```

Answer (score 0):

as an example to compress every individual `.jpg`
`cd dir/`

```
for f in `ls -1 *.jpg` ; 
do
     7z a  "$f.7z" "$f" ;
done
```